# Storing and retrieving data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm currently using Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS 5.
I tried using SQlite3 but i could not insert or update any data as i always get this error "attempt to write a readonly database".
after searching i find that this is something related with apple that you cannot copy the database into the Documents directory to be writeable!

is there any other easy way to solve this problem or use another method of storing the data?

thanks

Comment: You can copy the database to your Documents directory and make it writeable.  If you tried and it didn't work, show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a *much* better method of storing data: Core Data.  If you are interested, this is a [good place](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get started.

Apple has pretty much dropped almost all of the documentation on SQLite and switched over to Core Data.  Core Data also has a performance boost, so there isn't a a reason *not* to use it.

Comment: Isn't Core Data built on top of SQLite?

Comment: @Oil Yes, but there is still a performance boost and it's much easier to manage.

Comment: Also, because CoreData is an abstraction, if Apple decides to leverage any technology other than sqlite in the future, it will still work :)

Answer (score 1):

Word of advice: You should be saving it to library/cache directory.  This is so that it's not backed up by iTunes or iCloud.  I say this only because my app was rejected for this reason.

[iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/)

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

it is the standard way with apple devices to handle read/writeable files in documents directory only. you cannot write to any file if it is in your application resource and you must copy it to document directory to write anything to it.